# Unable to contact Active Directory through pyad

Tags: active-directory, pyad

I'm not able to connect to pyad module to create Active Directory objects. I'm getting an exception as shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\sparava\PycharmProjects\imds_ad_pycliient\venv\lib\site-packages\pyad\adobject.py", line 135, in from_cn
    return cls(adsearch.by_cn(cn, search_base, options), None, options)
  File "C:\Users\sparava\PycharmProjects\imds_ad_pycliient\venv\lib\site-packages\pyad\adsearch.py", line 17, in by_cn
    type="GC")
  File "C:\Users\sparava\PycharmProjects\imds_ad_pycliient\venv\lib\site-packages\pyad\adquery.py", line 78, in execute_query
    self.__rs, self.__rc = command.Execute()
  File "<COMObject ADODB.Command>", line 3, in Execute
  File "C:\Users\sparava\PycharmProjects\imds_ad_pycliient\venv\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 287, in _ApplyTypes_
    result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Active Directory', 'The server is not operational.\r\n', None, 0, -2147217865), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

"The server is not operational" means that it cannot contact the server.

I assume `type="GC"` means that it is trying to contact the Global Catalog, which is on port 3268 by default, unless you specifically specified a different port.

So all this means that it cannot open a connection to your AD server on port 3268.

Maybe it's a network issue, or maybe it's a configuration issue in your application. If you update your question with your code, I might be able to spot something that looks off, or maybe not